# I want to add safari webdriver extention to safari on windows 8 64 bit machine

Tags: safari, safari-extension

I want to add safari webdriver extention to safari on windows 8 64 bit machine.

When I am installed safari browser with version 5.1.7. It is automatically get updated to 
webdriver extention but on another machine I am not able to add same webdriver extention.

Refer a figure http://imsardine.simplbug.com/note/selenium2/drivers/safari.html

I want to add same extention to same  windows 8 64 bit machine where windows update are off. 
On that machine we can not turn windows update off. When I am searching for update I am unable 
to find that extention.

Answer (score 0):

Apple has stopped updating Safari on windows...so you have to follow this work around to get it updated to the latest version...

If you are still using Safari 5.1 for Windows (e.g. for the excellent font smoothing), you can keep up with modern web browsers by upgrading its WebKit engine to the latest version released by Apple.

Just follow these steps:

1. If you have iTunes already installed, go to step 5.
2. Download the latest release of iTunes for Windows.
3. Open the downloaded file iTunesSetup.exe in an archive manager, like 7-Zip or WinRAR.
4. Extract the file AppleApplicationSupport.msi and run it. Complete the installation.
5. Copy the folder C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Apple\Apple Application Support (or without (x86) when on 32-bit system) to C:\Program Files (x86)\Safari and merge with the existing Apple Application Support folder.

When you restart Safari, you will notice much better HTML5 & CSS3 support (319 -> 342 points in HTML5 Test) and JavaScript performance. Enjoy!